# How to change antd pro-component's SettingDrawer text/locales from default Chinese to English

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro, pro-components, pro-layout

I am integrating antd's pro-components, specifically `@ant-design/pro-layout` according to their [document](https://procomponents.ant.design/en-US/components/layout#basic-usage). I have converted all Chinese text to English except text in `SettingDrawer` component. Screenshot attached

Here is the playground https://codesandbox.io/s/ji-chu-shi-yong-forked-lxtxqp (`Note: open the output to a new window otherwise it wouldn't work`).

One additional piece of info is that antd's original playground does not work as it missed to import the required CSS. Need to import the following

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
```

[image]

Comment: I opened your codesandbox in a new window and itt doesn't appear to have Chinese characters in the settings drawer for me.

Comment: I am still seeing the words in Chinese. I am talking about the words highlighted with yellow color, in case my question was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the language globally by using `ConfigProvider`

See Doc: https://ant.design/docs/react/i18n#configprovider

```js
import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd';
import frFR from 'antd/locale/fr_FR';

return (
  <ConfigProvider locale={frFR}>
    <App />
  </ConfigProvider>
);
```